# How to make the background control editable when drawn over the some other control in it

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

We have to provide the selection support for `RichTextBox` so i have created separate control and drawn over it using `Paint()` method. Problem was I am not able to edit the `RichTextBox` once done the drawing over it. Please find the below attached simple sample and share your ideas.

Note : We have suspect issue due to setting the selection control dock style as Fill but if i remove or changed then selection not drawn.

[image]

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private GraphicCellControl graphiccell;

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {

        #region picturebox

        this.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;

        var selectBtn = new Button();
        selectBtn.Size = new Size(100, 30);
        selectBtn.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        selectBtn.Text = "Click";
        selectBtn.Click += selectBtn_Click;

        //var picturebox = new PictureBox();
        //picturebox.Size = new Size(140, 110);
        //picturebox.Location = new Point(4, 4);
        //picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        //picturebox.Image = new Bitmap(@"..\..\Data\picture.png");

        var richtextbox = new RichTextBox();
        richtextbox.Size = new Size(140, 110);
        richtextbox.Location = new Point(4, 4);
        richtextbox.Text = "Texting information";

        graphiccell = new GraphicCellControl();
        graphiccell.Location = new Point(50, 200);
        graphiccell.Size = new Size(150, 120);
        graphiccell.Controls.Add(richtextbox);
        this.Controls.Add(graphiccell);
        this.Controls.Add(selectBtn);

        #endregion

    }

    void selectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        graphiccell.IsSelected = !graphiccell.IsSelected;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class GraphicCellControl : Control
{
    private SelectionControl selectionControl;
    public GraphicCellControl()
    {
        selectionControl = new SelectionControl();
    }

    private bool isselected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isselected; }
        set
        {
            isselected = value;
            if (isselected && !this.Controls.Contains(selectionControl))
            {
                this.Controls.Add(selectionControl);
                selectionControl.BringToFront();
            }
            else if (!isselected && this.Controls.Contains(selectionControl))
                this.Controls.Remove(selectionControl);
        }
    }
}

public class SelectionControl : Control
{
    public SelectionControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.Opaque |
                 ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       // Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Gray, 1), 4, 4, this.Size.Width - 10, this.Size.Height - 10);

        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, 0, (this.Size.Height - 10) / 2, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, 0, this.Size.Height - 10, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, (this.Size.Width - 10) / 2, 0, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, (this.Size.Width - 10) / 2, this.Size.Height - 10, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, this.Size.Width - 10, 0, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, this.Size.Width - 10, (this.Size.Height - 10) / 2, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, this.Size.Width - 10, this.Size.Height - 10, 8, 8);

        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), 0, 0, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), 0, (this.Size.Height - 10) / 2, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), 0, this.Size.Height - 10, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), (this.Size.Width - 10) / 2, 0, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), (this.Size.Width - 10) / 2, this.Size.Height - 10, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), this.Size.Width - 10, 0, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), this.Size.Width - 10, (this.Size.Height - 10) / 2, 8, 8);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2), this.Size.Width - 10, this.Size.Height - 10, 8, 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that you are painting on a control that is nested in a RTB in order to support coloring parts of the RTB text?? You should of course color the text directly, as this ability is what the Rich in RTB stands for! If I got you wrong, please explain a little more what you are drawing! An image might help..

Comment: I mean selection support is to draw the border around richtextbox so i have done it by creating selection control and drawn the border over the richtextbox from the onpaint() .

Comment: Please look into the attached image as "Reference image" on top

Comment: Hm I see the image but no richttextbox. Again: What kind of selection is this meant to be? an image area? a part of the text in the RTB? The RTB itself?? Please explain!

Comment: you can see the rich text box in the image and the ellipse border around the image is selection drawn from the paint(). Issue is  ** i can't edit the rich text box  after drawn the border around the rich text box ** .  if you have time please try to run the code i have used

Comment: Ok, I thought so but I still do not understand just what 'selection' is supposed to mean here? What is selected? For what purpose? Resizing the RTB? The issue is clear but the purpose isn't..

Comment: If you mean to visibly 'select' the RTB control (or others) I think I would go for the opposite way: Instead of putting a selection frame __above__ it, I  would place one __below__ the control and make it a few pixels larger to make room for the handle ellipses! While it is __maybe__ possible to make it work the way you try by redirecting the `WndProc` messages I doubt it will be worth it! - The other classic solution is using separate modes for editing content and layout..

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem, as I understand it is that your overlay control will intercept all user intercivity.

This goes not just for the mouse actions. It also includes keyboard actions, setting the focus and updating the display after any changes.

It may be possible to workaround all those issues by redirecting all relevant `WndProc` messages but it will be rather complicated.

Here is a simpler solution: Instead of **overlaying** the RTB with the selection frame put that frame **under** the RTB. I have created a modified class and it works rather well, although one would maybe tweak the sizes of the handles, make them dynamic  and getting the respective offsets right but you surly can do that..:

[image]

The class is basically the same as yours; I just added a few properties and a `Select` method:

```
Point oldLocation = Point.Empty;
Control oldParent = null;
BorderStyle oldBorder = BorderStyle.None;

public void Select(Control ctl, bool selected)
{
    if (selected)
    {
        Parent = ctl.Parent;
        oldLocation = ctl.Location;
        ctl.Location = new Point(8, 8);
        Location = Point.Subtract(oldLocation, new Size(8, 8));
        Size = new Size(ctl.Width + 16, ctl.Height + 16);
        oldParent = ctl.Parent;
        oldBorder = (ctl as RichTextBox).BorderStyle;        // optional
        (ctl as RichTextBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None; // optional
        ctl.Parent = this;
        this.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        ctl.Location = oldLocation;
        ctl.Parent = oldParent;
        (ctl as RichTextBox).BorderStyle = oldBorder;   // optional
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

I didn't include the `BorderStyle` logic at first; I think it is the reason for a few cut off pixels. Not hard to get right..!

Also note that to get the colors completely right you need one more `FillRectangle` to avoid letting the parent `BackColor` bleed into the selection frame, depending on what color you have..:

```
if (Controls.Count > 0)
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Controls[0].BackColor))
           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 4, 4, Width - 10, Height - 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the research finally i got a solution by placing this method in the selectioncontrol :

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
                return cp;
            }
        }
```